# Unit testing a private property in view controller loaded from the storyboard

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, private

I have a view controller called SubMenuViewController and a label in it called selectionLabel. The view controller is present in the storyboard and I am writing unit tests for testing SubMenuViewController.

I have a method:

```
- (void)drawerItemSelectedWithIndex:(NSInteger)selectionIndex 
{
    if(selectionIndex == 0)
    {
        self.selectionLabel.text = @"All";
    }
    else
    {
        self.selectionLabel.text = @"Test";
    }
}
```

I want to write unit test cases for this. I have created an extension.

```
@interface SubMenuViewControllerTests : XCTestCase
@property(nonatomic)SubMenuViewController *subMenuViewController;

@end

@interface SubMenuViewController()
@property(nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *selectionLabel;
@end
```

And This is the test method I have written:

```
-(void)testDrawerItemSelectedWithIndex
{
    [self.subMenuViewController drawerItemSelectedWithIndex:0];
    XCTAssert([self.subMenuViewController.selectionLabel.text isEqualToString:@"All" ]);
}
```

Is this the right way to test this method, as I am getting value of self.subMenuViewController.selectionLabel as nil.

Comment: I have done this in setUp:

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your view controller from the storyboard so that the outlet is wired up properly.

Comment: I have initialised the view controller in set up.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code? Is your storyboard variable nil? In my view controller tests, I have to specify the bundle for my main app in order to find the Main storyboard

Comment: I'm initializing the instance of self.subMenuViewController in the setUp. I'm doing something like self.subMenuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubMenuViewController"] but even after that the label is not initialized.